# Print on the same line in Python 3 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Trying to print

```
Numbers are: 1 2 3 4 5
```

from here

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
print("Numbers are: "),
for n in numbers:
    print(n),
```

But it doesn't print numbers in same line, it prints them on new line, why? I am on Python 3.

Comment: you should check the documentation before asking on stackoverflow:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Thank you for comment, I take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `python 3.x` you have to use `print(..., end =" ")` to substitute the new line with an empty space for example.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
print("Numbers are: ", end =" ")
for n in numbers:
    print(n, end =" ")
```

Comment: Wow! This is working, why? Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, this is a duplicate as  @jonrsharpe has found out. Please try not to answer if it is a duplicate (and check for duplicates before answering)

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
print(n, end=" ")
```

because:

Python’s print() function comes with a parameter called ‘end’. By default, the value of this parameter is ‘\n’, i.e. the new line character.